# Como redireccionar a una pagina después de hacer click en salir

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

Esta es mi situación, cuando un usuario se registra en mi pagina, le sale una ventana de que ha completado el registro satisfactoriamente, para salir de esta ventana debe darle click a el botón x, cuando sucede esto solo lo deja en la misma pagina de registro.

Lo que deseo seria esto: Después de darle click al botón x, que se redirija al inicio y aparte ya este loggeado(que inicie sesión automáticamente)

Gracias por su ayuda.

El código debería ser este

```
echo '<div class="col-sm-4 col-sm-offset-4 text-center"><div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">'.__("Registration complete.","themeum").' <a href="'.get_permalink( get_option('login_page_id') ).'">'.__("Sign In","themeum").'</a></div></div>'; }
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Desde el 25 de mayo de 2011, los estados de la especificación HTML5 que llaman a los métodos window.showModalDialog(), window.alert(), window.confirm() y window.prompt() pueden ser ignorados en este evento.

De hecho desde la versión 51 de Chrome, 44 de Firefox, 38 de Opera y 9.1 de Safari, se removio el soporte para mensajes personalizados en este evento.

Lo que puedes hacer es a través de ajax, realizar el registro y en el success (callback a ejecutar cuando la petición se ha ejecutado satisfactoriamente) puedes hacer el login y dejar el usuario en este contexto.

Para realizar esto debes desacoplar el render de la aplicación, es decir la parte del front end y la parte del backend (PHP o lo que sea que uses en el servidor), de tal forma que puedas implementar el flujo de aplicación

Registro -> Login

Para esto requieres revisar la documentación de JQuery AJAX, Json, cómo devolver datos en json desde el servidor. Y entender el concepto de almacenamiento local de datos en cliente, render de html5 con json y templates con javascript.

Se que es un poco general, pero es una aproximación para solucionar tu proyecto.

Saludos,

Comment: muchas graciass